# AWS PrivateLink Fargate 1.4:ResourceInitializationError:unable to pull secrets or registry auth:execution resource retrieval failed:ecr registry auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I am a beginner at AWS services. I am getting this Error:

"ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ecr registry auth: service call has been retried 3 time(s): RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post https://api.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp 52.**.***.105:443: i/o timeout"

Some details that might help you help me:

- Setting up "Run task" in 2 private subnets. (should it be one?)
- In the "Run task" , I am using the same security group associated with my VPC endpoints
- In the Service , I am using the same security group associated with my VPC endpoints
- I am using a "Network Only" cluster.
- I am using a task definition of type "Fargate"
- For the task definition container, I am leaving port mappings blank
- For Task execution role in task definition I have: ecsTaskExecutionRole
- I am leaving "Mesh integration"/"proxy configuration"/" FireLens integration" unchecked
- Auto-assign public IP: "Disabled"

My goal is to run an instance of my app in a private subnet and connect it to AWS resources through PrivateLink. I DO NOT intend on setting up an internet gateway/NAT device/AWS direct connection/VPN. I am almost sure I am missing something. Thorough explanations will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "2 private subnets" - do they have access to the internet or use interface endpoints?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Marcin isn't your question answered in the last paragraph of the question? "My goal is to run an instance of my app in a private subnet and connect it to AWS resources through PrivateLink. I DO NOT intend on setting up an internet gateway/NAT device/AWS direct connection/VPN."

Comment: This is likely the problem: "In the "Run task" , I am using the same security group associated with my VPC endpoints
In the Service , I am using the same security group associated with my VPC endpoints"  Being in the same security group does not automatically confer any connectivity between resources. It just opens the same ports on both services. Please provide the actual security group rules of the security group(s) in your question.

Comment: Hello @MarkB. Thank you for reaching out. Here are the details of my security group:
Inbound rules : IP(v4)/type(all traffic)/protocol(all)/port range(all)/source(0.0.0.0/0).
outbound rules: IP(v4)/type(all traffic)/protocol(all)/port range(all)/destination(0.0.0.0/0).

Comment: So everyone. I found out the issue. I just had to create endpoints for ecs,ecr,S3 and cloudwatch.  Heres the link to some directions. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/setting-up-aws-privatelink-for-amazon-ecs-and-amazon-ecr/